# getting error : Module 'mailchimp-api-v3' is not listed as dependency in package.json

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I want to add newsletter functionality with `mailchimp`, So I have installed `mailchimp` node module, but when I run my function, It gives me this error 
`Module 'mailchimp-api-v3' is not listed as dependency in package.json` can anyone please help me why I am getting this error?

Comment: Can you post your `package.json`? What command you have used to install dependency? What is your path of the project?

Comment: @HardikShah i found the issue,  it is not listed in my package.json, because i installed it in wrong directory, it was my bad, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You must install it from the directory where your `package.json` is:

```
npm install mailchimp --save
```

With the --save option, the command will update your `package.json` file for you with the new dependency.

Comment: it was my bad, i have installed it in wrong directory